# Comparing data types in "if" statements in C#?

Tags: c#, if-statement

So, I'm creating a simple calculator getting started into programming in C# and I've had two issues so far that I have not been able to solve.

The first being that for some reason, of all operators/symbols, it won't let me add the "-" operator/symbol alongside a string. It only allows me to have the "-" operator with my variables alone. (I tried using double instead of decimal but got the same error).

The second (and more important) being that I'm trying to have an if statement that gives a message (and run another method) when the user inputs the wrong data type. Any way to solve this (or at least find a work-a-round)?

Thanks!

Here's a sample of the code containing both issues:

```
    static void Calc()
        {
            Console.Write("\n\nPlease enter a number here: ");
            decimal num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.Write("Please Specify an operator: ");
            string op = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Please enter another number: ");
            decimal num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

            if (op == "+")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + num1 + num2);
            }
            else if (op == "-")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + num1 - num2);
            }
            else if (op == "*")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + num1 * num2);
            }
            else if (op == "/")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + num1 / num2);
            }
            else
            {
                OpElse();
            }

            if (num1 || num2 != Decimal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must input a number");
                Else();
            }
```

Comment: You can use `decimal.TryParse` to determine if the value the user entered is actually a decimal or not.  Using `Convert.ToDecimal` will thrown an exception if the entered values cannot be parsed.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

`Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + num1 - num2);`

It will add firstly `num1` to the `string`, and then will try to subtract number from string, which is invalid. Use parenthesis `"some string" + (num1 - num2)`
Same error will happen with addition as well, for example: `"a" + 5 + 2`  will result in: `a52`

To check if entered data is incorrect, TryParse can be used, or same Convert.ToDecimal but with try catch

```
    Console.Write("\n\nPlease enter a number here: ");
    decimal num2 = 0; // Assigning default value so compiler doesn't comlain
    try 
    {
        num2 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
        //do something else
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, although, when I use "try" and "catch" the variable is declared as new instead of using the one already declared. 
`Console.Write("\n\nPlease enter a number here: ");
            decimal num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            
            try
            {
                decimal num1 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (FormatException num1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must input a number");
                Else();
            }`
sorry for formatting weirdness there

Comment: Oh and by the way, thanks for the first solution, I feel super dumb for messing that up :)

Comment: Variable should be declared outside of try catch. I'll update the answer to reflect that. And you don't need to parse twice

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to have an if statement that gives a message (and run another method) when the user inputs the wrong data type. Any way to solve this (or at least find a work-a-round)?

You can try the [`Decimal.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) method, which will attempt to parse a string to a decimal, but wont throw an exception if it fails. It would look something like this:

```
if (!Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out decimal num1)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("No no my friend. You have to enter a valid number.");
}
```

> ..of all operators/symbols, it won't let me add the "-" operator/symbol alongside a string. It only allows me to have the "-" operator with my variables alone. (I tried using double instead of decimal but got the same error).

That has to do with [*operator precedence*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/). In fact, even though minus is the only one that complains at compile time, the addition gives you are wrong result at runtime. The problem is just that the (first) `+` is being evaluated before the `-`. That results in the first number being added to the string, before doing the calculation. To fix this, simply wrap the calculation part in parenthesis:

```
Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + (num1 - num2));
```

or move the calculation out of the string concatenation:

```
var result = num1 + num2;
Console.WriteLine("The answer is: " + result);
```

Comment: Oh my goodness thank you so much. Although, when I try the `if (!Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out decimal num1))` it says that num1 is already defined. sorry, I'm such an amateur. Do you know to fix this?

Comment: Everybody starts out an amateur. :) You get that error because the `out decimal num1` part, actually defines a new variable called `num1`. So you can't define another variable with the same name later. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

num1 and num2 are always going to be decimal type so checking if their type is a decimal is unnecessary. If you want to display a message when parsing fails, look into using `decimal#TryParse()` which will return true if it parsed correctly, false if not.

As for your - sign issue. I'm not too sure what you mean but I'm assuming you're trying to do something like `-"some string"` which is invalid C# code. Decimal could convert negative numbers just fine when typed out, assuming you don't put a space between the minus and the number itself.

Or if you're trying to do something like `"num1 - num2"` that won't work unless you use string interpolation `$"{num1+num2}"` for an example

Comment: Thank you!! that helps

Answer (score 0):

You correctly pointed out two problems:

### 1. Operator Failure

The `+ - * /` operators.  Remember order of operations, `* /` are first, `+ -` are second, then left to right in groups of equal order.  So in the write statements the `* /` get executed before the `+`.  Resulting `string + decimal`, and since there is implicit converter from decimal to string the `+` operator acts as a concatenation.

In the case of `-` the order is `string + decimal - decimal`, which from left to right means the first `+` concatenates two strings.  However, `-` is not an operator on `string` and therefore fails.

Try using the `$"Answer is: {num1 + num2}"` syntax for each case (changing the operator as required).

### 2. Logic Failure

You are converting and throwing a runtime exception in the `Parse` method prior to the tests and out put.  As suggested, use `TryParse` and place the error case at the top.